# "Session is closed" error even after making a new aiohttp.ClientSession

Tags: python-3.x, session, web-crawler, python-asyncio, aiohttp

**Description of intent**: What I'm trying to do is use asyncio and aiohttp to retrieve the data off some websites **fast**. Sometimes, the website sends 50* errors and I'm trying to brute force the 200 responses by calling the function again and again until there are no 50* errors in responses left. Basically, if I have 50 urls and 15 of them are 50*, I will call the function again with those 15, etc. up until there's no non-200 responses left. I know this is not a good practice, but there are reasons why I'm doing this which are not the topic of this conversation.

The problem I'm having is that, once the initial run finishes (the first 50), when I call the 15 50*s left, "session is closed" error pops up, even though I just created a new session within "compile_calls_get" function. I suppose there's something I don't quite understand about sessions.

The code:

```
import asyncio
import ssl
from typing import Optional, Any
import aiohttp
import creds

ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=creds.PROXY_PATH)
connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=ssl_context)
proxy = "example_proxy"


async def fetch_get(url: str, session: aiohttp.ClientSession) -> Any:
    async with session.get(url=url, proxy=proxy) as response:
        data = await response.text()
    return {"success": response.status, "url": url, "data": data}


async def compile_calls_get(url_set: list,
                            headers: Optional[dict] = None,
                            ssl_verify: bool = False) -> tuple:
    if ssl_verify:
        aiohttp_session = aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers, connector=connector)
        async with aiohttp_session as session:
            extracted_data = await asyncio.gather(*[fetch_get(url=url, session=session) for url in url_set])
        return extracted_data
    else:
        aiohttp_session = aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers, connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False))
        async with aiohttp_session as session:
            extracted_data = await asyncio.gather(*[fetch_get(url=url, session=session) for url in url_set])
        return extracted_data


def extract_data_asynchronously(url_set: list,
                                headers: Optional[dict] = None,
                                ssl_verify: bool = False) -> list:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    data = loop.run_until_complete(compile_calls_get(url_set=url_set,
                                                     headers=headers,
                                                     ssl_verify=ssl_verify))
    return data
```

This block of code is how I send requests asynchronously.

This block of code is the one which calls "extract_data_asynchronously":

```
urls = ["some_url", "some_other_url"]
final_results = []
iterations = 0
headers = {"some_value": "some_value"}

while True:
    iterations += 1
    responses = extract_data_asynchronously(url_set=urls,
                                            headers=headers,
                                            ssl_verify=True)
    responses_list = []
    for response in responses:
        if response['success'] != 200:
            responses_list.append(response['url'])
        else:
            final_results.append(response)
    if len(responses_list) == 0:
        break
    print(f"Remaining invalid responses: {len(responses_list)}. Run number: {iterations}")
```

I also tried these options:

Making a session from within "async with" statement:
`async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers, connector=connector) as session:`

I tried calling "**aenter**", "**aexit**" statements manually.
Closing session manually with `session.close()`.
I tried stopping / closing the loop but it pops errors.

From what I gather the problem is that some coroutines are not finished? But I thought loop.run_until_complete makes sure that they are finished before continuing.

Any and all help is welcome.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test/module1.py", line 254, in <module>
    verify('a')
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test/module1.py", line 215, in verify
    responses = module2.extract_data_asynchronously(url_set=responses_list,
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test/module2.py", line 65, in extract_data_asynchronously
    data = loop.run_until_complete(compile_calls_get(url_set=url_set,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test/module2.py", line 31, in compile_calls_get
    extracted_data = await asyncio.gather(*[fetch_get(url=url,
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test/module2.py", line 16, in fetch_get
    async with session.get(url=url,
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 400, in _request
    raise RuntimeError("Session is closed")
RuntimeError: Session is closed
```